# Set indentation style per file extension in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have multiple file types that are not in the editor -> code style list. They require different indentation (one requires tabs, while the other requires spaces). Setting the "other file types" indentation only covers one of them, and doing a 12 or 16 space indentation with just the spacebar or copy/pasting tab characters are two a great ways to get angry quickly.

How can I set the indentation on a per file extension basis?